Anomaly detection for Multivariate Time-Series data from multiple sensors
I work with tabular time-series data from multiple sensors and my goal is to detect abnormal behavior in battery discharge.
Here is an example of data (example contains records only for one device with ID = 1981. Number of devices in table is 30_000+):




Timestamp
ID
Type
Battery
Temperature




18019
2020-01-02 00:02:44+00:00
1981
10
4033
16


35569
2020-01-02 23:57:34+00:00
1981
10
4026
17


53378
2020-01-04 00:02:38+00:00
1981
10
4026
17


71094
2020-01-05 00:00:05+00:00
1981
10
4033
16


107159
2020-01-07 00:03:18+00:00
1981
10
4060
16


124632
2020-01-07 22:58:43+00:00
1981
10
4052
16


124925
2020-01-07 23:58:28+00:00
1981
10
4052
16



Most of devices send data once or twice a day. Sometimes some events happen and in this case device can send data more then twice a day. On some days there can be no records at all.
Example of discharging plot (red points - point of recharging or replacing batteries):

Here are preprocessing steps I've made:

Group data by ID and Day (from 'Timestep') to get 1 record per day for each device (take last record for each day to detect how much the battery discharged on this day)
Added new column 'count' which contains number of records per day for each device
Added 1 day lag for Battery and Temperature (to be able to catch immediate anomalies like abnormal drop of battery value or temperature difference) and 1 week lag (to monitor how the battery is discharging over a more significant period of time then 1 day).




Timestamp
Battery
Temperature
count
ID
Type
Battery_day_lag
Temperature_day_lag
Battery_week_lag
Temperature_week_lag




2020-01-07 00:00:00+00:00
4052.0
16.0
3
198146
3
4060.0
16.0
4033.0
16.0


2020-01-07 00:00:00+00:00
5788.0
9.0
2
2595
2
5816.0
6.0
5716.0
5.0




Then instead of absolute values in lag columns I got relative values (by substracting Battery and Temperature values from lag columns respectively)




Timestamp
Battery
Temperature
count
ID
Type
Battery_day_lag
Temperature_day_lag
Battery_week_lag
Temperature_week_lag




2020-01-07 00:00:00+00:00
4052.0
16.0
3
198146
3
8.0
0.0
-19.0
0.0


2020-01-07 00:00:00+00:00
5788.0
9.0
2
2595
2
28.0
-3.0
-72.0
-4.0




And for all Battery and Temperature columns I applied robust scaling.

In the end my data looks like this:



Battery
Temperature
count
Battery_day_lag
Temperature_day_lag
Battery_week_lag
Temperature_week_lag
Type_2
Type_3
Type_4




0.713043
0.000000
3
0.153846
0.0
-0.447059
0.00
0
1
0


-0.086754
-0.636364
2
0.538462
-1.5
-1.070588
-1.00
1
0
0


-0.388060
-0.090909
1
-0.442308
-0.5
-0.305882
-0.25
1
0
0


-0.307836
-0.454545
1
-0.269231
-0.5
-0.905882
-0.25
1
0
0


-0.342351
-0.363636
1
-2.903846
-1.0
-0.141176
-0.25
1
0
0



Then I built an encoder model:
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from keras.optimizers import Adam

keras.utils.set_random_seed(1)

input_dim = X_train_ohe.shape[1]
l1 = 15
l2 = 9
l3 = 5
bottle_neck = 3

autoencoder = Sequential([

    Input(shape = (input_dim, )),

    # deconstruct / encode
    Dense(l1, activation='elu'),
    Dense(l2, activation='elu'),
    Dense(l3, activation='elu'),

    # bottle neck
    Dense(bottle_neck, activation='elu'),
    
    # reconstruction / decode
    Dense(l3, activation='elu'),
    Dense(l2, activation='elu'),
    Dense(l1, activation='elu'),
    Dense(input_dim)
    
])

autoencoder.compile(optimizer = Adam(learning_rate = 1e-3), 
                    loss = "mse")

And it works ok for obviously anomaly points (for example is able to detect temperature values > 80 degrees or huge drops of battery value in Battery_day_lag). And here is the thing:

Basically this model can be replaced with if-condition + threshold for each feature (e.g. if df.Temperature > 80: !Anomaly!) which makes sense considering preprocessed data. Maybe there are some better approaches in preprocessing or model selection that I missed?

Tree-based models (Isolation forest) are not sutible there. LOF model could work fine but it is too 'heavy' in terms of calculations. Convolutional models would give the same result as an encoder model I assume. What other kind of model can be used there?



Just to clarify, are you trying to make anomaly predictions at the level of battery-day, ie. on this day, this battery was anomalous, in that we are treating each battery independently?

@Alex every day I get records from multiple devices (which contains current battry level and temperature) and the final goal is to be able to detect if a certain device battery is discharging abnormaly. I grouped records by 'ID' + 'day' because most of devices sends at least 1 record per day (it is predefined behavior)
